# React Js : Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting below error in my react app. Not sure what is the issue.

/Users/823222/miniapp/node_modules/headers-polyfill/lib/Headers.js 9:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:25)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ../../node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | class HeadersPolyfill {
  |     // Normalized header {"name":"a, b"} storage.

> ```
> [NORMALIZED_HEADERS] = {};
> ```

|     // Keeps the mapping between the raw header name
|     // and the normalized header name to ease the lookup.

Comment: You're using array destructuring syntax on an object. That's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is due to a recent change in this package, that changed how the symbols were declared:

https://github.com/mswjs/headers-polyfill/pull/33/files

*I've started a GitHub issue here, feel free to add details about your environment:
https://github.com/mswjs/headers-polyfill/issues/36*

**TL;DR: There was a significant change to how the module is prepared in a recent release, I reverted to 3.0.4 and things are working again for me.**

Edit:
3.0.10 released that reverts the build target and fixes this issue:
https://github.com/mswjs/headers-polyfill/releases/tag/v3.0.10

Comment: Yep. Using the latest version of the "headers-polyfill" should be enough.